# Align elements below an object with the elements above

Tags: html, css

I have a two column grid that holds a header element above a paragraph tag (on the left column) and a input box above a submit button (on the right column). I want the left edges of these items to align and for some reason they won't. I have the margin-left of all the elements at margin-left:0px; For some reason the button appears aligned on codepen but not on the site.

```
.latest-from-aer .input-email {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

https://codepen.io/holmedw/pen/KrvJEb?editors=1100

[alignment issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFx7S.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your button is an `inline-block` element which means it's affected by `text-align`. On your site there's probably a parent element with `text-align: center` that doesn't exist on your codepen.

Add `text-align: left` to the wrapping div it will probably solve your problem.

As you have it in codepen this would look like:

```
#form {
 text-align: left
}
```

(Also note that in codepen you have your submit button as an `<input>`, you'll probably want to make that a `<button`)

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked on the button but the "latest from aer"/ "don't miss out on new arrivals" text does not right align when I do this : .contact-paragraph-hearder .contact-paragraph {
  
  margin-left: 0px;
}

Comment: If you want that to apply `margin-left` to both classes you need to add a comma: `.contact-paragraph-hearder, .contact-paragraph { margin-left: 0px; }`. As you have it above, you're telling the browser to look for a `.contact-paragraph` that's a descendant of `.contact-paragraph-header`. [descendant selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) vs [grouping selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp).